# NewsFeed Webpart Out of box question

Tags: web-part, newsfeed

NewsFeed webpart comes with a subject view. I was wondering if there was a way to remove "my discussions", "Unanswered questions"..[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can control the ViewSelector with JavaScript (Client Side Rendering)

See StackOverflow questions and answers:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=SurfacedPivotCount

Comment: Thanks, how about if I want to remove the "+new discussions" string.
Also, can I hide the elipsis(...) in the above step..

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to remove view selector menu from your view/form

Please refer following steps :

1. GoTO your view page
2. Append "**?toolpaneview=2**" and hit the url (this will open your page in edit mode) or go to settings and click on edit page.
3. Edit Web Part
4. tik/check "**Disable view selector menu**" and "**disable Save this view button**"

[image]

5. Apply and OK

Comment: Rohit, I did that and did not work.